# Doubt in understanding the definite integrals

Tags: calculus

A question came up in my mind about "definite integrals and the fact that it provides us a way to calculate the area under the curve by writing it as the limit of a sum". The question maybe silly but I am unable to make a way out.

We consider a continuous and differentiable function $f(x)=x^2$.
Now if we are trying to find out the area under the graph of the function between the points $x=a$ and $x=b$ ($b>a>0$).
First we partition our interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ number of small disjoint intervals of equal length.
Consider the expression $\frac{b-a}{n}=h$.
Let we define a sequence $g(n)$ as follows:
$g(n)=h[f(a)+f(a+h)+.............+f(a+(n-1)h)]$
Now as $n$ will grow larger and larger the sequence $g(n)$ more and more closer to the required area under the graph. When I draw by making $n$ larger and larger it feels quite assuring that as $n$ tends to infinity , $g(n)=$ required  area under the graph.
$g(n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of positive real numbers  which is bounded above by the required area under the graph and bounded below by $0$, so $g(n)$ must converge to the supremum of its range set.
How to prove that the supremum of this sequence will be our required area under the graph? By drawing it's ok to visualize the fact but how can it proved mathematically that the supremum will be our required area?

Comment: What is the definition of area that you are using?  The area is often defined to *be* that integral, and we just justify the definition intuitively.  If you want a proof, you somehow have to define the area independently of the integral.

Comment: Consider using MathJax for formatting. In this case you really just have to put dollar signs around the equations/symbols.

Comment: Do you have the same difficulty if we replace $f$ with a constant function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to prove that statement rigorously we need to first make *sense* of it rigorously - and to do that we need to have some formal definition of area to start with. Since that's exactly what integration is intended to get us, this is a bit circular.

That said, there's a basic result which gets the ball rolling, namely **the convergence of the upper and lower Riemann sums**. Intuitively, each lower Riemann sum should be a lower bound on the area and each upper Riemann sum should be an upper bound on the area, so their joint limit has to be the exact area.

In the particular case you're looking at, this is something you can - and should! - prove by hand.

---

Of course this isn't really rigorous since - as said above - we don't have already have a formal definition of area. However, it motivates the following first stab at a definition of area:

> Suppose $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b]$. We say that *the area under the graph of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ equals $A$*, and write $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=A,$$ iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ with $x_{i+1}-x_i<\delta$ for each $i$ the associated upper and lower Riemann sums are each within $\epsilon$ of $A$.

Here we're being a bit more general than you may expect by allowing Riemann sums with *uneven* rectangle widths. In fact we're going to want to be **much** more general very soon: we'll want to look at the areas given by **possibly discontinuous** functions, in which situation "upper" and "lower" sums may not make sense, and consequently the full definition of the Riemann integral is somewhat more complicated.

*And [even that's not the end of the story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration), but that's getting a bit far afield.*